# use strict leads to undefined function

Tags: jquery, function, undefined, use-strict

I am trying to organize my js file and followed a suggested module pattern. When I use "use-strict" in this pattern a function is declared as undefined, without the "use-strict" method the function just works fine. Is the strict-mode recommended and when yes, why does the function not work with the use of it?

```
var envy = (function( $ ) {
   'use strict';

   /**
    * Viewport adjusments.
    *
    * @since 1.0.0
    */
   irp_viewportadjst = function() {
      $('meta[name="viewport"]').attr('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0');
   },

   /**
    * Fire events on document ready, and bind other events.
    *
    * @since 1.0.0
    */
   ready = function() {
       irp_viewportadjst();
   };

   // Only expose the ready function to the world
   return {
       ready: ready
    };

   })( jQuery );
jQuery( envy.ready );
```

Comment: Strict mode is recommended because it catches mistakes. The function doesn’t work with it because it contains mistakes, like undeclared variables and an unintentional comma. Looks like it originally had a `var` above `irp_viewportadjst` that got lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable declaration hoisting is required in your code. Strict mode declaration demands your function name to be defined earlier.
Either define your function name 
`var irp_viewportadjst, ready;` or
Change the code as below

```
var envy = (function( $ ) {
   'use strict';

   /**
    * Viewport adjusments.
    *
    * @since 1.0.0
    */
   var irp_viewportadjst = function() {
      $('meta[name="viewport"]').attr('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0');
   };

   /**
    * Fire events on document ready, and bind other events.
    *
    * @since 1.0.0
    */
   var ready = function() {
       irp_viewportadjst();
   };

   // Only expose the ready function to the world
   return {
       ready: ready
    };

   })( jQuery );
jQuery( envy.ready );
```

Comment: yes this works. However, could you explain me, why the tutorial (gamajo.com/javascript-module-pattern-example) seems to work without the use of the var on every function? I'd like to build up the custom file like the tutorial, so do I need to make every function a variable?